# How to get data local storage data in json object in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to emberjs and currently in learning phase.
I have saved form data in localstorage using ember data and localstorage-adapter.
Now I want that data in json object.
Can anyone explain me how to get localstorage data in json object?

I am creating record using following code:

```
Grid.ModalModel.createRecord({
  fname: fname, lname: lname, email: email,
  contactno: contactno, gendertype: gendertype, contactype: contactype
});
this.get('store').commit();
```

Data is saved in the browser's localstorage. Now I want that data in a json object in the controller for further use in application.

Comment: Please share some code so we can see what you've tried

Comment: @Gevious :  I am creating record using following code                                    Grid.ModalModel.createRecord({ 
       fname: fname,
       lname: lname,
       email: email,
       contactno: contactno,
       gendertype: gendertype,
       contactype: contactype
     });
     this.get('store').commit();   now data is saved in localstorage of browser,now i want that data in json object in controller for further use in application.